# Loading Google Maps on backbone

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js, coffeescript, brunch

I'm using backbone to develop a maps application. How do load the google script asynchronously without using the google loader? I'm trying to use $.getScript, but for some reason, the google global object it returns doesn't have any of the standard API functions like google.maps.LatLng.

My Code

```
$.getScript 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=false', ->
  console.log google
  mapOptions = 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  map = new google.maps.Map document.getElementById("map")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax instead of getScript:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'script',
    data: params,
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js'               
});
```